# Why does raw_input not prompt correctly?

Tags: python, networking, tcp, twisted, kademlia

I'm attempting to use the kademlia library featured here:
https://github.com/bmuller/kademlia
My code is as follows:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.python import log
from kademlia.network import Server
import sys

log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

def done(result):
        reactor.stop()
        print "Key result:", result

def get(result, server):
        key = raw_input("Key:")
        server.get(key).addCallback(done)

def set(found, server):
        key = raw_input("Key:")
        message = raw_input("Message:")
        server.set(key, message).addCallback(get, server)

server = Server()
server.listen(8468)
server.bootstrap([("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 8468)]).addCallback(set, server)

reactor.run()
```

Its taking input and operating on that input correctly.  However instead of the input prompts displaying correctly.  For example KEY: or MESSAGE:  I just get a blank line.

What a i doing wrong here?

Comment: you should change that _key_ inputs.Just make them different like _key_ and _keya_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logging is interfering with the process's standard out.

Try removing the line `log.startLogging(sys.stdout)` and you should find that `raw_input()` displays the prompt.